# Create a coupon in woocommerce for first time orders with an expiry date of 2 weeks upon creating the account

Tags: woocommerce

I am new to e-commerce development, I need help in implementing **coupon code for first order** feature with an expiry date of 2 weeks upon creating the account in [Woocommerce](https://woocommerce.com/).

Below is the code I tried so far, but it is not working as expected.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$userregisterddate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(get_userdata(get_current_user_id())->user_registered)); 
$userregisterddate;
$expirationdate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($userregisterddate. ' + 13 days'));

$coupon_data = new WC_Coupon('myfirst');
$today = date('d-m-Y');
$fixedDate = implode('', array_reverse(explode('-', $expirationdate)));
$variableDate = implode('', array_reverse(explode('-', $today)));

if ($variableDate > $fixedDate){

    echo"Hello World be Happy Always!!! :)";
      $couponId = get_option('_fodw_coupon_id');

        wp_delete_post( $couponId, true ); 
        delete_option($couponId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You may check this free plugin**

Global Coupons for Woocommerce - published on Wordpress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/global-coupons-for-woocommerce/

Plugin contains features like **coupon for First Order** and **coupon activate between dates**. I believe these two features will help your implementation. You can inspect those codes from: https://github.com/MrEbabi/Global-Coupons-for-Woocommerce-Plugin/blob/master/global-coupons/core/global-coupon-operations.php

In github code, use CTRL+F with "//first order" and "//activate on the given date interval" for the relevant functions.

It is licensed under GNU so you can get the relevant code for your work and edit it as you want.

**Alternatively source code for your problem**:

Code goes to functions.php of your active child theme or theme. It will create an admin menu named "testtttt". When you click to this menu item, it will generate a coupon code named "test_coupon" with fixed_cart discount and amount of $10. Then it will restrict it with only new users (registered in last 14 days) and those without any orders. You can click this menu item anytime you want but it will not duplicate the coupon code, just updates it. If you want it to generate and update the coupon continuously and automatically, instead of adding "test_coupon()" function to admin menu, add it to "wp_footer" hook, so it will run every page loads.

```
function test_coupon()
{   
    $_newCouponID = 0;
    $isCreatedBefore = false;
    $args = array(
        //get all coupons that starts with string GC
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'orderby'          => 'title',
        'order'            => 'asc',
        'post_type'        => 'shop_coupon',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
    );

    $coupons = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $coupons as $coupon )
    {
        $_coupon = wc_get_coupon_code_by_id($coupon->ID);

        if($_coupon == "test_coupon")
        {
            $isCreatedBefore = true;
            $_newCouponID = $coupon->ID;
        }
    }

    if(!$isCreatedBefore)
    {
        $_couponName = "test_coupon"; 
        $_couponAmount = 10; //discount value
        $_couponType = "fixed_cart"; //or "percent"

        //create new coupon
        $_newCoupon = array(
            'post_title' => $_couponName,
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon',
            );
        $_newCouponID = wp_insert_post( $_newCoupon );

        $randomaizeEmail = rand();
        $tempEmail = "noone$randomaizeEmail@noone.com";
        update_post_meta( $_newCouponID, 'discount_type', $_couponType );
        update_post_meta( $_newCouponID, 'coupon_amount', $_couponAmount );
        update_post_meta( $_newCouponID, 'usage_limit_per_user', '1' );
        update_post_meta( $_newCouponID, 'individual_use', 'yes' );
        update_post_meta( $_newCouponID, 'customer_email', $tempEmail );
        wp_update_post($_newCouponID);
    }

    //check user registration date and first order
    $users = get_users();
    $emails = array();
    $count_active_users = 0;

    foreach( $users as $user ) 
    {
        $udata = get_userdata( $user->ID );
        $registered = $udata->user_registered;
        $register_date = date("d m y", strtotime( $registered ) );

        $register_day = substr($register_date, 0, 2);
        $register_mon = substr($register_date, 3, 2);
        $register_year = substr($register_date, 5, 4);

        $today = date("d m y");
        $today_day = substr($today, 0, 2);
        $today_mon = substr($today, 3, 2);
        $today_year = substr($today, 5, 4);

        $isRegisteredTwoWeeks = false;

        if($today_year == $register_year && $today_mon == $register_mon && (($today_day-$register_day)<14) ) $isRegisteredTwoWeeks = true;
        if($today_year == $register_year && (($today_mon-$register_mon)==1) && (($today_day-$register_day+30)<14) ) $isRegisteredTwoWeeks = true;

        $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => $user->ID,
            'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
            //only for on-hold, processing and completed orders
            'post_status' => array('wc-on-hold','wc-processing','wc-completed'),
        ) );

        $isThisFirstOrder = false;
        $user_info = get_userdata($user->ID);
        $customer_email = $user_info->user_email;

        if(count($customer_orders)==0) $isThisFirstOrder = true;

        if($isThisFirstOrder && $isRegisteredTwoWeeks)
        {
            array_push($emails, $customer_email);
            $count_active_users++;
        }
    }

    if($count_active_users)
    {
        update_post_meta( $_newCouponID, 'customer_email', $emails );
        $update_post = array(
            'ID' => $_newCouponID,
            'post_excerpt' => 'New Customer - First Order - 14 Days',
        );
        wp_update_post($update_post);
    }

}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'testtttt' );
function testtttt() {
    add_menu_page( 'testtt', 'testtt', 'manage_options' , 'testtttt' , 'test_coupon', 'dashicons-warning' , '1');
}
```

I hope that works. Have a good day.

Comment: Thankyou for your help I have tried using plugin and github code aswell but nothing seems to work in my case I want every individual when creates the account then a coupon code is created for the first order will activate for that user from its registration date to  next 13 more days after that it will expire if the user has not used that code after 14 days of registration

Comment: Plugin works like this: You can create a global coupon for first orders (without time restriction) and users who are recently signed up to your website can see this coupon code in their My Account / Coupons page. But plugin does not provide first order coupon with time restriction for now.

Comment: I can add this feature (first order + time restriction) to the plugin this weekend if you want?

Comment: Okay yes please add in the free version, how to activate coupon status as I have created one but its status is inactive there is no option to activate

Comment: It is programmatically checks if you are a new customer (means this user does not have any orders), if your current account has no order then the plugin will be shown as activated for this account.

Comment: I can do it tomorrow, then I will update the plugin. I hope you like to use it. Have a good day.

Comment: Yes I can see this by creating new account

Comment: okay, I want it to work like based on user registration date with an expiry date of 2 weeks upon creating the account. with a fixed price  for first-time orders

Comment: Ok i will do my best.

Comment: Glad to hear this. Thank you @MrEbabi

Comment: When I add coupon in cart page then it was displaying the amount after deduction but when I add the same coupon in checkout page it doesn't have an effect on the price I have to add twice this coupon because in checkout it was showing the original price.

Comment: Code that I mentioned "Alternatively" is tested and works fine. Have a good day.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: please help me is there any way not to reload test rather create a coupon on every user register